# Matrix Transform of Rectangle after changing its bounds

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, matrix, transform

I have a shape, for example a Rectangle which has the following bounds:

```
X = 100
Y = 100
Width = 100
Height = 100
```

I apply the following rotation to this rectangle using a new `Matrix`:

```
X = 100
Y = 100
Angle = 45

var transform = new Matrix();
transform.RotateAt(angle, point);
```

So the new Matrix has the following value:

```
0.7071068, 0.7071067, -0.7071067, 0.7071068, 150, -62.13202
```

I use this Matrix when I draw the Rectangle with `Graphic`:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    e.Graphic.Transform = transform;
    g.DrawRectangle(Pen, bounds.X, bounds.Y, bounds.Width, bounds.Height);
}
```

The problem is the following: at a certain point I need to draw the same Rectangle but shifted by a certain offset, for example (50, 50). I have stored the Matrix transform and the Rectangle bounds. If I change only the bounds (adding the offset) the new Rectangle will be drawn in a wrong position, probably due to the previous rotation point.

How I have to change the Matrix in order to draw my Rectangle in the "right" position? that is, how can I retreive the right rotation point and the old rotation angle?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add translation to the matrix using `MatrixOrder.Prepend`.
For offset `(50, 50)` it'll be:

```
transform.Translate(50, 50, MatrixOrder.Prepend);
```

Or create a separate matrix for this case:

```
var transformWithOffset = new Matrix();
transformWithOffset.Translate(50, 50);
transformWithOffset.RotateAt(angle, point);
```

Comment: Because if my matrix stores a rotation of 45 degree, for example, the translation will be wrong. The rectangle will be translated along the X axis which is also rotated by 45°.

Comment: I have neither the angle nor the point, I only have the Matrix and the rectangle bounds...

Comment: I've updated my initial answer adding `MatrixOrder.Prepend` as a 3rd argument of the `Translate` method. Please revise.